# SSIS package fail due to 'acquire connection' error

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

New to SSIS. I'm attempting to run package, but each time it returns: "**Failed to acquire connection [ConnectionName]**. Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection."

The connection uses `SQL login` and when deployed I specified - Rely on server storage for Encryption (ServerStorage). The login itself has the appropriate privileges being the sa account.

The **SSIS package** is located on the on the SQL server.

Any suggestions on how I can bypass this problem?

Comment: refer this article which may help u http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918760

Comment: Configuration issue, now resolved.